# Adding a jar file to CLASSPATH is still not executable

Tags: linux, java, zsh, jar, classpath

Perhaps I just don't understand how the whole `CLASSPATH` environment variable works when trying to find .jar files on your system. I thought if you specified it, you could launch .jar files with `java` in much the same way that you can launch executables that are on your path.

I have an executable java archive (`.jar` file) on my system, that I stuck in `/usr/local/bin/gatk/`. I added this to my `CLASSPATH` via:

```
export CLASSPATH=/usr/local/bin/gatk/GenomeAnalysisTK.jar
```

I thought this would make the `.jar` file visible to my JVM. When I try to invoke it with

```sh
java -jar GenomeAnalysisTK.jar
#Error: Unable to access jarfile .gatk/GenomeAnalysisTK.jar
```

I can invoke it setting the absolute path, e.g.
`java -jar /usr/local/bin/gatk/GenomeAnalysisTK.jar`, however I'd rather not type the full path each time. I have read many of the linked tutorials but somehow I don't seem to be getting this right and I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CLASSPATH` is not meant to search for jars. It is meant to search for classes. Putting a jar in `CLASSPATH` means java will see the classes *inside* the jar, but not the jar itself.

What you want is more likely a shell script wrapper starting the jar.

Create a text file containing the following lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar /usr/local/bin/gatk/GenomeAnalysisTK.jar
```

Make the file executable (suppose you name it `GenomeAnalysisTK`):

```
chmod +x GenomeAnalysisTK
```

Put that file in `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin` or wherever you want provided the path is in your `$PATH`.

From now on you can call the shell script and it will start the jar. No need to mess with `CLASSPATH` anymore.

---

Alternatively: with the jar in the classpath you can start the main class from inside the jar like this:

```
java org.broadinstitute.sting.gatk.CommandLineGATK
```

The main class of the jar is specified in the file `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` inside the jar. For more information see the [wikipedia article about jar files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29).

Comment: Many thanks. I was going crazy. I don't have much experience using java based programs so that's a great help, thanks.